# what's differnt of two kinds of coding style for property

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is here any differences of two kinds of **title**?

```
@interface MyObject: NSObject{
    NSString *title;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first is an instance variable.

The second is a property.

Instance variables are largely deprecated as a part of a class's declaration (interface), but instance variables used internally to the class can be declared in an extension or the @implementation.

Properties declare both the API (the setter/getter) and the memory management model employed.  By default, a modern compiler will automatically synthesize the instance variables to back a property.

Answer (score 1):

The above one is not property, but just an instance variable.
My opinion here:

1. Use the newest Xcode.
2. Do not write instance variable : `@interface MyObject : NSObject {
       NSString *title; }`
3. Use `@property` only, and no need to explicitly `@synthesize` it,
   Xcode will implicitly `@synthesize title = _title;` where the
   `_title` is the instance variable to support property `self.title`.

This is a kind of good coding style, I think.